# Using installed identity certificate from within an app on iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, security

My question is: is there a way to use the installed identity certificates on the phone from within my app. For example similar case like with Safari: if certain site requires client certificate, the user has to install it on the phone and then when authenticating Safari uses the installed certificate to authenticate. I need to do the same:

1. User installs certificate on the phone.
2. The user starts the application and authenticates using the installed certificate.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean authenticate an NSURLConnection to a specific server? I think you can do this if get into some of the lower level CF calls. Not sure, but this might help:  [Does SecTrustEvaluate() look for root certificates in the application keychain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4669255/does-sectrustevaluate-look-for-root-certificates-in-the-application-keychain/7661606#7661606)